# How to simulate click event for SignIn button https://www.linkedin.com/

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

i'm writing a browser plugin and trying to simulate a user click on the login button.
I have tried

```
document.getElementById('signin').click();
```

URL : https://www.linkedin.com/

but this is not working. I'm kind of new to Java script can some please give some guidance how to achieve the same.

Comment: What's not working about it? It's disabled by default so you have to enter values into the textboxes first, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off submitting the form itself:

```
document.getElementById('login').submit();
```

I tested that in Chrome Dev Tools.

Answer (score 1):

1-in linkedin you can't click on signin button unless the username and password is filled.
2- you have to use the id of the signin button which is 'btn-login' not 'signin'
 so it would be
 document.getElementById('btn-login').click();

Answer (score 0):

The script you have written will work for Internet Explorer.  But for other browsers it wont work. You can try the following code.

```
function simulateClick() {
  var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
  var cb = document.getElementById("signin"); 
  var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
  if(canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}
```

Please go through this link for more information

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent